# Best Practice - Convert SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Can anybody advise how to convert the SQL below to LINQ?

```
SELECT distinct EmployeeID
  FROM Employee,
       Business
 WHERE Administrator = 1 or 
         (BusinessID = 1 and
         (EmployeeID = Initiator or
          EmployeeID = Owner))
```

Or perhaps suggest a better way of achieving the same result using more than one expression? I've read LINQ can be buggy so I presume the more complex the query, the more likely problems are to occur?

Comment: `I've read LINQ can be buggy` -- [citation-needed].  I assume that what you really mean is that not every SQL statement can be converted to LINQ.

Comment: I've been using linq for years, and I've yet to see any bugs.

Comment: It is not buggy, but the more complex the query the more horrendous the SQL output. We're going through an exercise where were taking existing LINQ and EF queries and rewriting them by hand in more performance critical areas of our application.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.linqpad.net/whylinqbeatssql.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I shouldn't believe everything I read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want just:

```
var query = (from employee in db.Employee
             from business in db.Business
             where employee.Administrator == 1 ||
                 (business.BusinessId == 1 &&
                  (employee.EmployeeId == business.Initiator ||
                   employee.EmployeeId == business.Owner))
             select employee.EmployeeId).Distinct();
```

I've guessed at which column belongs to which table...